# How to get the available jdk versions in install-jdk library of python?

Tags: python, java-11

I want to get all the *jdk versions* that available/supported for the time.
I know the install-jdk library, but I think there's no function to get them, or I didn't notice.
Do you know a way to get the jdk versions that the install-jdk can install?

```
import jdk

# like the example:
jdk.install("11")
```

but I want something like this:

```
versions = jdk.get_available_versions()
print(versions)
```

But there's not such a function I think..

Comment: Thanks for your responses :)
I think I am gonna use something else to do the thing I wan to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.

If you look at [the code](https://github.com/jyksnw/install-jdk/tree/master/jdk/client), you will see that the `Client` classes actually don't know what the available versions are.  Rather, they all<sup>1</sup> just assemble a URL for the downloadable using whatever the caller provided as the version string, and then just attempt to connect to that URL.

Given that web servers are not file systems, there is probably not a simple way (i.e. without gnarly webpage scraping) to query the download sites to find all available versions.  (But ... hey ... there's nothing stopping you from trying.)

---

<sup>1 - ... at the time of writing</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The default vendor (source) is Adoptium.

Adoptium support the following version (https://adoptium.net/fr/temurin/releases/):
8-LTS, 11-LTS, 16, 17-LTS, 18, 19, 20, 21-LTS.

```py
versions = jdk.get_available_versions()
# Is equivalent to
versions = ["8", "11", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"]
```

Edit:
Following Stephen's comment, here is what I think is a more sustainable approach:

You could parse the result to a call to the Adoptium API getting all available releases.

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.adoptium.net/v3/info/available_releases"
headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

This gets you a JSON that you could then parse into a list if you want.

Comment: But that will probably change in 6 months time, and again in 12, 18 and so on.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer to reflect that. It will still break if Adoptium no longer provide the API.